Need help in creating Azure Search Index
I'm trying to create search index in azure ai search. I have json documents in blob storage.
But I'm facing some errors which I'm not able to resolve.
This is the error that I can see in the debugging session.
There's a mismatch in vector dimensions. The vector field 'vector', with dimension of '1536', expects a length of '1536'. However, the provided vector has a length of '0'. Please ensure that the vector length matches the expected length of the vector field. Read the following documentation for more details
Seems like some of the chunks from output of text splitter is empty, but I have validated that input to splitter is not empty.
I'm pasting the skills in skillset json file.
"skills": [
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
  "name": "SplitTextSkill",
  "description": "Split combined text into chunks of 4096 characters",
  "context": "/document",
  "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
  "textSplitMode": "pages",
  "maximumPageLength": 4096,
  "pageOverlapLength": 0,
  "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "source": "/document/combined_text"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "textItems",
      "targetName": "chunks"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
  "name": "Embeddings generation",
  "description": "Azure OpenAI Embedding Skill",
  "context": "/document/chunks/*",
  "resourceUri": "endpointOfAzureOpenaiService",
  "apiKey": "<redacted>",
  "deploymentId": "akm-aml-embeddings",
  "dimensions": 1536,
  "modelName": "text-embedding-ada-002",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "source": "/document/chunks/*"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "embedding",
      "targetName": "vector"
    }
  ],
  "authIdentity": null
}

]

please add your index definition.

Also the indexer defination

The error tells that the output from embedding model is having the length zero, which is not matching with the index field having 1536 dimensions.
So, check whether your embedding model giving correct output or not
in debug session like below.

If you see output and you still getting the same error then below are possible reason.

Output from embedding model is empty so try changing the model.
Output field mappings not done properly give the proper field mappings. In your case it will be

"outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/chunks/*/vector",
      "targetFieldName": "fieldname_in_index"
    }
  ],


At last try recreating the index and re run the indexer.

If the you are not getting output as shown in above image then try to give the embedding model which gives correct output.
Also, you are getting output of all the chunks from each document so try to do  index projection to secondary index instead of doing output field mappings.
